# What is the fastest way to deal with large arrays of data in Android?

Tags: java, android

could you please suggest me (novice in Android/JAVA) what`s the most efficient way to deal with a relatively large amounts of data?

I need to compute some stuff for each of the 1000...5000 of elements in say a big datatype (x1,y1,z1 - double, flag1...flagn - boolean, desc1...descn - string) quite often (once a sec), that is why I want to do is as fast as possible.

What way would be the best? To declare a multidimensional array, or produce an array for each element (x1[i], y1[i]...), special class, some sort of JavaBean? Which one is the most efficient in terms of speed etc? Which is the most common way to deal with that sort of thing in Java?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick, you've asked a very generally questions. I'll do my best to answer it, but please be aware if you want anything more specific, you're going to need to drill down your question a bit.

Some back-envolope-calculations show that for and array of 5000 doubles you'll use 8 bytes * 5000 = 40,000 bytes or roughly 40 kB of memory. This isn't too bad as memory on most android devices is on the order of mega or even giga bytes. A good 'ol ArrayList should do just fine for storing this data. **You could probably make things a little faster by specifying the ArrayLists length when you constructor. That way the Arraylist doesn't have to dynamically expand every time you add more data to it.**

Word of caution though. Since we are on a memory restricted device, what could potentially happen is if you generate a lot of these ArrayLists rapidly in succession, you might start triggering the garbage collector a lot. This could cause your app to slow down (the whole device actually). If you're really going to be generating lots of data, then don't store it in memory. Store it off on disk where you'll have plenty of room and won't be triggering the garbage collector all the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I`ll consider an ArrayList then!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the efficiency with which you write the computation you need to do on each element is way more important than the data structure you use to store it. The difference between using an array for each element or an array of objects (each of which is the instance of a class containing all elements) should practically be negligible. Use whatever data structures you feel most comfortable with and focus on writing efficient algorithms.